# Windows 8 Metro style project(InkStroke.Add Error)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Windows 8 Metro style project.

After deleting some strokes I'm trying to add the deleted stroke using the `InkManager.AddStroke()` method to provide undo and redo functionality.

An exception is thrown

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Comment: possibly duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206693/windows-8-how-to-undo-redo-ink-using-built-in-inking-functionality/15568648?noredirect=1#comment22154879_15568648

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void OnDrawUndo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BackupInkStrokeCollection.Push(CurrentInkStrokeCollection.Pop());
            renderer.Clear();
            renderer.AddInk(CurrentInkStrokeCollection);

            //inkManager.GetStrokes()[inkManager.GetStrokes().Count - 1].Selected = true;

            InkStroke SelectedStroke = inkManager.GetStrokes()[inkManager.GetStrokes().Count - 1];
            SelectedStroke.Selected = true;
            var MyInkManager = new InkManager();
            MyInkManager.AddStroke(SelectedStroke.Clone());
            MyInkManagers.Add(MyInkManager);
            inkManager.DeleteSelected();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            if (ee.Message == "Stack empty.")
                return;
            else
                new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ee.ToString()).ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```